# load the data dynamically by id on button click in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, fetch-api

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'

class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      fetchdata: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          data: json,
        });
      });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
      this.fetchdata();
  }

fetchdata=()=>{
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/:id")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
          this.setState({
            fetchdata: json.data,
          });
        });
}

  render() {
    const { data, fetchdata } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Todos row g-3">
          <table class="table col-auto">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Todo</th>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.data.map((data, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <th scope="row">{data.id}</th>
                  <td>{data.title}</td>
                  <td>{data.completed}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={this.fetchdata.bind(this, data)}>
                      View
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
              ;
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div className="show-data col-auto">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Todo_Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Todo_title</th>
                <th scope="col">User_id</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.fetchdata.map((fetchdata, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <th scope="row">{fetchdata.id}</th>
                  <td>{fetchdata.name}</td>
                  <td>{fetchdata.email}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
              ;
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Todo
```

This is my code I want to load data on button click but I am getting an error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') ". I am new to react js and don't know how to do it. The data is not getting loaded in the below table on button click by id. The first table data is loading correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were few issues

1. `id` was not passed as a param to `fetchdata`
2. respnse data was `JSON` not an `Array`
3. DO NOT call any function in `componentDidUpdate` without checking prev state. There was an infinite loop calling the API.
4. No need to bind `fetchdata` function as it is an arrow function.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      fetchdata: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          data: json
        });
      });
  }

  fetchdata = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        this.setState({
          fetchdata: json
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { data, fetchdata } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Todos row g-3">
          <table class="table col-auto">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Todo</th>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.data.map((data, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <th scope="row">{data.id}</th>
                  <td>{data.title}</td>
                  <td>{data.completed}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={() => this.fetchdata(data.id)}>
                      View
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
              ;
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div className="show-data col-auto">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Todo_Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Todo_title</th>
                <th scope="col">User_id</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.fetchdata && (
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">{fetchdata.id}</th>
                  <td>{fetchdata.name}</td>
                  <td>{fetchdata.email}</td>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Todo;
```

[image]
Sandbox code => https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-parm-c0l54?file=/src/App.js:0-2277

Comment: @Gaurav, check this out !!

Comment: Only accepting for the first id, not for others, e.g check for the last one.

Comment: @Gaurav, Api response is empty for the last id. Check this => https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/200

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to react i highly recommend you to use hooks, but there are several things you can do in your Code:

1-Fetch data(you need id i Think, so):

fetchdata=(id)=>{
fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((json) => {
this.setState({
fetchdata: json.data,
});
});
}
This Way you pass the id by arguments.

2- onClick función:

View

As you Will need the id to pass it to the fetch función. No need bina with fan Arrow function

3- This is the Code i suggest for hooks:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const Todo = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [fetchdata,setFetchdata] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      setData(json);
    });
  },[])


  const fetchdataById = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        setFetchdata(json)
      });
  };

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Todos row g-3">
          <table class="table col-auto">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Todo</th>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {data.map((data, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <th scope="row">{data.id}</th>
                  <td>{data.title}</td>
                  <td>{data.completed}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={() => fetchdataById(data.id)}>
                      View
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
              ;
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div className="show-data col-auto">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Todo_Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Todo_title</th>
                <th scope="col">User_id</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {fetchdata && (
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">{fetchdata.id}</th>
                  <td>{fetchdata.name}</td>
                  <td>{fetchdata.email}</td>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }


export default Todo;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Something like this should Work,

Comment: It is also not working!

Comment: I just edited it, sorry, nos its working

Answer (score 0):

here's what you can do:

```js
class Todo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      fetchdata: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          data: json
        });
      });
  }

  fetchdata = (todo) => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + todo.id)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          fetchdata: json
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { data, fetchdata } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Todos row g-3">
          <table className="table col-auto">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Todo</th>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {data.map((todo, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <th scope="row">{todo.id}</th>
                  <td>{todo.title}</td>
                  <td>{todo.completed}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={() => this.fetchdata(todo)}>View</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div className="show-data col-auto">
          <table className="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Todo_Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Todo_title</th>
                <th scope="col">User_id</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{fetchdata.id}</th>
                <td>{fetchdata.name}</td>
                <td>{fetchdata.email}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Todo />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```